# reorder rows by group based on another index value in r

Tags: r, grouping, string-matching

Is a way in Base R to reorder data based on a column value by group?
For example, if I have a data set m:

```
name  v1   v2   v3
a1     4    1    2
a2     1    3    2
a3     1    5    2
b1     1    2    2
b2     1    4    2
b3     1    3    2
c1     6    1    2
c2     5    1    2
c3     4    1    2
```

and I have another index vector only for each group, meaning that if my data has 3 groups a, b,c, this index vector only has 3 rows:
2
3
1

and now I want to reorder my dataset based on this index vector (ascending, 1,2,3), so the order of the group should be c, a, b, but no order change within group, like below:

```
name  v1   v2   v3
c1     6    1    2
c2     5    1    2
c3     4    1    2
a1     4    1    2
a2     1    3    2
a3     1    5    2
b1     1    2    2
b2     1    4    2
b3     1    3    2
```

Is there a way to do that, in Base R? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a named index vector `v`,

```
v <- c(a=2, b=3, c=1)
```

in base R you could use `match` to create a temporary `id` column in the following way, then `order` your result.

```
ds1$id <- v[match(substr(ds1$name, 1, 1), names(v))]
ds1[order(ds1$id), -5]
#   name v1 v2 v3
# 7   c1  6  1  2
# 8   c2  5  1  2
# 9   c3  4  1  2
# 1   a1  4  1  2
# 2   a2  1  3  2
# 3   a3  1  5  2
# 4   b1  1  2  2
# 5   b2  1  4  2
# 6   b3  1  3  2
```

Without the `"name"` column you could `split` the rows in `seq`uences of length `n`, `sample` them and `rbind` them back together.

```
ds2 <- ds1[2:4]  ## generate data w/o "name" column

n <- 3
do.call(rbind, sample(split(ds2, rep(seq(nrow(ds2)/n), each=n))))
#     v1 v2 v3
# 3.7  6  1  2
# 3.8  5  1  2
# 3.9  4  1  2
# 1.1  4  1  2
# 1.2  1  3  2
# 1.3  1  5  2
# 2.4  1  2  2
# 2.5  1  4  2
# 2.6  1  3  2
```

With the division by `n` has a remainder, as it's the case with `n=4` you'll get a warning, and excess lines are assigned to other groups. Don't know if that suffices for you?

---

*Data*

```
ds1 <- structure(list(name = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", 
"c2", "c3"), v1 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L), v2 = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), v3 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), id = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I will upvote as this solution is more practical and only uses the vector in `base-R` +1, I used a dataframe and it is very similar to yours.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. What if I don't have a first column a, b, c, and I want to change the order of the rows but only between groups, such as every three rows move together. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using only `base R` you would need a key dataframe to store your vector:

```
#Code
keys <- data.frame(name=c('a','b','c'),order=c(2,3,1),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Add
df$Index <- keys[match(substring(df$name,1,1),keys$name),"order"]
df <- df[order(df$Index),]
df$Index <- NULL
```

Output:

```
df
  name v1 v2 v3
7   c1  6  1  2
8   c2  5  1  2
9   c3  4  1  2
1   a1  4  1  2
2   a2  1  3  2
3   a3  1  5  2
4   b1  1  2  2
5   b2  1  4  2
6   b3  1  3  2
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(name = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", 
"c2", "c3"), v1 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L), v2 = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), v3 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `arrange` on a `factor` converted 'name' column with the digits removed and `levels` specified in the custom order or 'c', 'a', 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   arrange(factor(sub("\\d+", "", name), levels = c("c", "a", "b")))
```

-output

```
#   name v1 v2 v3
#1   c1  6  1  2
#2   c2  5  1  2
#3   c3  4  1  2
#4   a1  4  1  2
#5   a2  1  3  2
#6   a3  1  5  2
#7   b1  1  2  2
#8   b2  1  4  2
#9   b3  1  3  2
```

---

Or using the same syntax in `base R` only

```
df1[order(with(df1, factor(sub("\\d+", "", name), levels = c('c', 'a', 'b')))), ]
#   name v1 v2 v3
#7   c1  6  1  2
#8   c2  5  1  2
#9   c3  4  1  2
#1   a1  4  1  2
#2   a2  1  3  2
#3   a3  1  5  2
#4   b1  1  2  2
#5   b2  1  4  2
#6   b3  1  3  2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", 
"c2", "c3"), v1 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L), v2 = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), v3 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The order must be based on any of the columns of interest. If you want to order based on variable v1, then:

```
dad <- data.frame(names = paste0(rep(letters[1:3],rep(3,3)),1:3),v1=rnorm(9),v2=rnorm(9))
dad[order(dad$v1),]
```